# Creating database access denied

Tags: mysql, server, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

Here is what I've done:

```
user@name /my/path # mysql -u root -p<myPassword>  
mysql> create database spy;
```

But it throws:

> ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './spy' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

How can I fix it?

---

Noted that this:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Throws:

> ERROR 29 (HY000): File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Comment: Looks like a file system permissions issue. Your data directory has the wrong user/group or permissions.